# What's the best way to run a custom script if a launch argument exists on Linux's boot arguments?

Tags: linux

I would like to run a custom launch script of an argument is present on Linux's boot flags.

I was thinking I would just create a systemd service that run a bash script that checks on start up which checks for the presence of the flag using an approach like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
CMDLINE="$(cat /proc/cmdline)"

if [[ "$CMDLINE" == *"myflag"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
fi
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This should work just fine. I see nothing bad about it, why are you looking for a "better" way? ;-) Only this comparison looks tidier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/231298

Comment: Haha you ever just be suspicious that something is too easy? - but thanks, yeah works just fine

Comment: You can simply do this instead if you want simplicity: `grep -q myflag /proc/cmdline && echo "it's there"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy, a “better” way could be to use [a systemd generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html); you can set `SourcePath=/proc/cmdline` so that your generator uses the kernel boot parameters and proceed from there.

Sticking to systemd units, since that’s what you’re using, you can [specify a condition in the unit definition](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionKernelCommandLine=):

```
[Unit]
ConditionKernelCommandLine=myflag
```

Without using systemd specifics, your script does the job already, but if you want something more compact it can be rewritten as

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if grep -qw myflag /proc/cmdline; then
  echo "It's there."
fi
```

or even

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
grep -qw myflag /proc/cmdline && echo "It's there."
```

The `-q` flag tells `grep` to *not* output matches, and only reflect success or failure in its exit status; the `-w` flag ensures that only whole words are matched, so `notmyflag` won’t trigger.